# How to log into server using ssh connection (Im using helios)

Tags: linux, ssh, cron

My host has quoted me this:

> Have you checked that your php script runs OK from the command line? 
>   The cron process needs to activate the command-line version of php -
>   /usr/bin/php - because it can't by itself process php scripts without
>   an interpreter running.  So, I've set the job to run using the
>   command-line.
>
> You can check it by logging into the server using an ssh connection
>   and running the script like so:
>
> /usr/bin/php  `<script name>`

My question is how do I perform this below so that I can run the script:

> You can check it by logging into the server using an ssh connection
>   and running the script like so:
>
> /usr/bin/php `<script name>`

Does it require a particular software to or anything like that? I am a complete novice on this so please explain it to me in with as less technical words as possible.

All my scripts are transferred using filezilla, I don't know if this is important?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but this is ***way*** too basic for Server Fault -- this site is geared toward *professional* system administrators: We assume that you can figure out how to run `ssh` and connect to your system. If that is beyond your skills you really need to hire a sysadmin, or spend some time with Google (search for `how to use SSH`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using linux, you can simply open your terminal and then type:

```
ssh yourusername@yourservername
```

and then log in with your password.

If you are the windows kind of guy, you may need to install putty and then issue the command above